Mariadb 10.11 on Debian 12 and character_set_database
I have a stock mariadb instance on debian 12 with no edits to the config files.
When I create a table w/o specifying character set and collation, the table is created with latin1 and it's collation.
The doc below says the server character set and collation are used when not explicitly set. That is not the case as I have character_set_server=utf8mb4 and collation_server=utf8mb4_general_ci
My understanding is setting character_set_database is deprecated. Yet I see it shown as character_set_database=latin1.
Bottom line: How do I get tables created with utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_general_ci w/o explicitly setting those values on CREATE TABLE statements?

Blockquote

MySQL chooses the database character set and database collation in the following manner:
If both CHARACTER SET charset_name and COLLATE collation_name are specified, character set charset_name and collation collation_name are used.
If CHARACTER SET charset_name is specified without COLLATE, character set charset_name and its default collation are used. To see the default collation for each character set, use the SHOW CHARACTER SET statement or query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA CHARACTER_SETS table.
If COLLATE collation_name is specified without CHARACTER SET, the character set associated with collation_name and collation collation_name are used.
Otherwise (neither CHARACTER SET nor COLLATE is specified), the server character set and server collation are used.

Blockquote


Use ALTER DATABASE and specify DEFAULT CHARACTER SET and DEFAULT COLLATION which you need in. After this the tables will be created with these settings when these settings are not specified. But explicit charset/collation specifying in CREATE TABLE is the best option/practice. PS. character_set_database setting is applied in CREATE DATABASE when you don't specify it. It does not effect the database which is already created.

Thanks for the comment, My understanding is you are not supposed to set character_set_database anymore. So still not sure on where the setting come from if not explicitly set in a statement.

In my opinion, if a setting may be specified in the statement then it must be specified. Including those ones which cannot be altered with server or session options and are set to default value when they're not specified - these default settings and/or their staticity may be altered in further versions, and upgrade may effect.

Well, I misinterpreted my situation. I failed to realize the database I was using was actually "imported" from another old instance. Hence, that's the reason why new tables were generated using latin1, etc. Creating a new database, then new tables in the db, did in fact result in character_set_server=utf8mb4 and collation_server=utf8mb4_general_ci on Debian w/o any change to a config file. My apologies for wasting your time.

Glad you worked it out - also https://mariadb.com/kb/en/character-sets/ is the MariaDB documentation. The similarities to MySQL documentation aren't guaranteed.
